# Organisation of applications in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony1

I'm looking to use Symfony as the framework for a gallery website - but I was wondering about how to organise the applications.

The example Symfony documentation takes a simple approach with a Frontend/Backend split - but this seems a bit limited.

For a gallery site, there are quite a few components which can interact to varying degrees - homepage, images, galleries, tags, comments, text pages, RSS feeds, etc.

I guess my question is - would I have an application for homepage, one for gallery views, one for gallery management, one for tags, etc? Things like tags can be applied to both images and galleries (and also maybe text pages).

Or should have these as modules within the simple Frontend/Backend split?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you read up further on Symfony to better understand the basic structure of a symfony project. The Jobeet tutorial available on the symfony website covers this. In brief, for what you describe, you would likely need:

- 1 application (frontend)
- multiple modules (homepage, gallery page, whatever page)
- some fragments such as partials and components for reusability

You would only need a backend application if you want some type of backend access, like for a CMS.

Comment: Yeah, I've been re-reading their documentation a few times since I posted - and that's pretty much the conclusion I drew. I wish their documentation was more generic/expansive than a set of tutorials, though, would have got there quicker.

Comment: Yep, this is the best there is: http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/   ....it's the same as the "definitive guide" but updated for Symfony 1.4